# display multiple posts and posts content on a single URL

Tags: posts, single

How can i display multiple posts and posts content on a single URL.
Like this https://www.recruitment.guru/ssc/ssc-recruitment/
showing posts on single post page.

Please suggest a solution.

Answer (score 0):

First you will need to create a [custom page template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/) and copy the styling from your page.php file. After that, you will use a loop below to display all posts in one page.###

```
<?php 
// the query
$wpb_all_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'post', 'post_status'=>'publish', 'posts_per_page'=>-1)); ?>

<?php if ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

<ul>

    <!-- the loop -->
    <?php while ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : $wpb_all_query->the_post(); ?>
        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <!-- end of the loop -->

</ul>

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php else : ?>
    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Create a category page in your theme and assign the category when publish new post. After that get all the posts of the category by coding in category page by using wp-query. Let me know if you need help regarding this